# Declaration expected when accessing structure variable VB

Tags: vb.net

What i am trying to do is just make an VB structure, and then assign things to the elements in the structure.

```
Structure Computer
    Public strModel As String
    Public dblCost As Double
End Structure

Public Class Form1

    Dim homeUse As Computer
    homeUse.strModel = "IB-50"
    homeUse.dblCost = 2400

End Class
```

from what i can tell in this code it is correct, but according to visual studios.

```
   homeUse.strModel = "IB-50"
   homeUse.dblCost = 2400
```

are incorrect because of the error "Declaration expected"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set the fields of the structure inline in the class declaration like that.  It would need to be inside a method, for instance the constructor:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim homeUse As Computer

    Sub New()
        homeUse.strModel = "IB-50"
        homeUse.dblCost = 2400
    End Sub
End Class
```